# What's wrong with this React Custom Hook?

Tags: react-hooks

I've read numerous articles on creating and using Custom Hooks in React but can't figure out why my code is not working.

Here is the heart of the problem code:

```
cont MyContextProvider = (props) => {  
  const useCompleteWizard = () => {
    // Define `body` object

    useEffect(() => {
      // const { loading, data } = useFetchPost(`${API_ROOT()}account_management/fleets`, body, app.awsConfig);
      useFetchPost(`${API_ROOT()}user_management/users`, body, app.awsConfig);

    }, []);
  }
}
```

Within my context provider, I've created the custom hook you see, which in turn calls another custom hook that posts the data.

But I'm getting this error:

```
React Hook "useFetchPost" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function.
```

I don't see that `useFetchPost` is being called inside a callback.  Which callback?  This just doesn't make any sense to me and I'm hoping someone can enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you are calling a custom hook inside useEffect callback.you know useEffect take
a callback function.please call your custom hook outside of this effect

please checkout this Invalid Hook Call Warning

https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html

Comment: Did you mean to say that I SHOULD BE calling `useFetchPost` from the return function of `useEffect` within `useCompleteWizard`?  I can see that I have not done this.  Is that the key to success?